# How to capture incoming and outgoing call data?

Tags: android, call

How can I capture 'voice data' from incoming and outgoing calls?

My intention is to intercept the transmission data of an application 'PhoneApps', do some work on it and transmit the data processed through the phone network before the other application can dispatch it to the phone network.

Answer (score 0):

> But my question is: how can I capture 'voice data' from incoming and outgoing phone calls?

You modify the firmware, and even that may not be able to do it. It certainly is not possible from an ordinary Android application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better look into intercepting audio data from mic and speaker rather than from phone itself assuming you can detect receiving/sending a call.

Comment: You can then capture the data from the microphone before it is forwarded to the application "PhoneApps"? and capture the data coming from "PhoneApps" before they are sent to the speaker?

It would be possible to catch them in a phone call so I can process this data before the User can listen to them and sends them processed by the telephone network?

Comment: @Kinfall Unless you are the author of the phone app that provides that kind of interface/service for other developers, I don't think it's possible.